Using CMakeLists.txt for WSL toolchain on CLion
I am trying to use WSL on CLion but I could not manage to use the CMakePresets.json and CMakeLists.txt file placed in project directory for WSL setting.
When I follow the instructions defined in CLion website it makes me to create a new cmake profile instead of using one of the configurations present in CMakePresets file and I did not understand how to make it use the CMakeLists.txt placed in project directory.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-product.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-projects-support.html#CMakeProfile
Is there a way to do that or is creating a new CMake profile the only way for using WSL on CLion?
